# SOQL Joins compared to SQL Joins

Tags: soql, query, sql, outer-join

What are the key differences between SOQL Joins and SQL Joins?

Comment: I've rewritten the actual question text to be in a format that invites proper answers, but I still feel it is overly broad for this site. Perhaps other community members will disagree. When you ask something like *could anyone help* or *could someone compare X and Y*, the straightforward answer is actually just yes or no. That style of question doesn't actually *ask* for the information you *seek*.

Comment: The Q is still 'On hold' from what I understand from the help center it will be closed automatically if not reopened, What I want to ask in this question Is give an example of SOQL Joins compared to SQL Joins, I master SQL more than SOQL for now, and I am sure there is people out there with a good SQL knowledge switching to SFDC and want to get a comparaison between the two. I wanted to document that on SFDC Stack, as I understand it's recommended to ask question an answer it, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a comparison inspired by [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com).

(*We suppose that we have an Account & Contact tables in a SQL database with the column Account as foreign key from Contact to Account*)

**Right Outer Join**

*SOQL*:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Account.Name FROM Contact
```

*SQL*:

```
SELECT con.FirstName, con.LastName, acc.Name 
FROM Contact con
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Account acc ON con.Account=acc.Id
```

---

**Left Outer Join**

*SOQL*:

```
SELECT Name,(SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

*SQL*:

```
SELECT acc.Name, con.FirstName, con.LastName
FROM Contact con
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account acc ON con.Account=acc.Id
```

---

Comment: Assume a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` isn't possible in SOQL?